# Action upon click within iFrame

Tags: jquery

I want to do some stuff upon a click on a `h1` tag within an `iframe`.

I have the code:

```
let iframe = $('#iFrame').contents();
iframe.find('h1').click(function() {
  console.log('click worked')
});
```

That I found in other queries on the same topic, but it's not working. I can't appear to do a `click` event on anything past `iframe.find('body')`

I can change CSS or perform other actions on elements within the `body`, but not `click`.

If it makes any difference, the `iframe` isn't being used traditionally, I'm loading content in to the `iframe` via jQuery, as it's being used as a device `viewport`, rather than loading external content.

Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: Are you waiting for the iframe content to load before executing this? If not, then the `h1` hasn't appeared on the page yet; you'd be attaching a click event to an element that doesn't yet exist. It would also be helpful if you could show where you define `iframe`.

Comment: Can i see your html code?

Comment: the debug step I always use for jQuery is `console.log(iframe.length)` and `console.log(iframe.find('h1').length)` to make sure they are actually matching anything.

Comment: Try $('#iFrame h1').click(function() {
  console.log('click worked');
});

Comment: Is the iframe pointing at the same domain? If not, you may be about to run into a lot of security restrictions.

Comment: Even "about:blank" is considered a different domain, by the way...

Comment: Thanks to Alessio for cleaning up the post, couldn't get the code block to close!

@TylerRoper The content from the iFrame gets loaded upon a click of its own (it's essentially a click based module builder. So do I need to wait until that click event has occurred before trying to attach this one?

Comment: @DBS The iFrame is empty, and gets loaded with content that exists on the same page. I've essentially built a viewport for a click based module builder

Comment: @SimonAustin That's correct. The alternative would be to use event delegation, but admittedly I'm not familiar with the behavior there as it relates to iframes.

Comment: Thanks @TylerRoper that worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved now. I've embedded this within a click event which adds content to the iFrame :)

Thanks for the responses!

Is there a way for me to resolve this post?